# Set initial Zoom on a Angular HighCharts Map

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I'm using:

@angular@15.2.7
highcharts-angular@2.10.0
highcharts@10.3.3

I've initialised my map like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArtistsService } from '../_services/artists.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import worldMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-geo-data',
  templateUrl: './geo-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./geo-data.component.sass'],
})
export class GeoDataComponent implements OnInit {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = 'mapChart';
  updateFlag = false;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {

    chart: {
      map: worldMap,
      styledMode: true,
    },
    
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      stops: [
        [0, '#00eab3'],
        [1, '#0645AD'],
      ],
    },

    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        alignTo: 'spacingBox',
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
   
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    
  };

}
```

with this template

```
<highcharts-chart id="container" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [constructorType]="chartConstructor" [(update)]="updateFlag" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>
```

Its a world map. The user can zoom in or out. But the map has to start on europe.

I've tried callbacks, events, update flags etc. But the map doesn't zoom in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this could work to set an initial zoom level.

```
    chart: {
      map: worldMap,
      styledMode: true,
      zoom: 2 // set the initial zoom level
    },
```